# How to add custom icons in editor action toolbar

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I want to add a custom icon on the editor action toolbar in vs code, which would be a link to a command. The icon should be visible alongside the file when any file is open on vscode. How to add the custom icon? Any leads would be helpful

[image]

Comment: which of the possible menu location contribution strings would be correct one, the doc has a finite number of possibilities and some are clearly not the correct one

Comment: @SachinDwivedi I need the same, were you able to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Add your custom command inside package.json under "editor/title" and "command". For more details check the following links:

1. [Editor Action](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/extension-guidelines#editor-actions)
2. [Contribution point](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/contribution-points#contributes.commands)

Answer (score 2):

To add an icon there, you'll need to edit your `package.json` file. Simply add a command and a menu contribution point that tells VSCode where to place the menu item

There is an answer here that has links to the VS code API documentation, but that documentation is very drawn out and doesn't give any good examples on exactly what you would put into your `package.json` file. So, I'll give a simple example of some real world code

package.json

```json
{
    ...
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "My.Custom.Command",
                "title": "Do Something",
                "icon": "$(run)"
            }
        ],
        "menus": {
            "editor/title": [
                {
                    "command": "My.Custom.Command",
                    "group": "navigation",
                    "when": "editorLangId == javascript"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

There are two items that are needed.

- The command under `contributes.commands`. That command should have an icon ([see the product icons reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/icons-in-labels#icon-listing))
- And where and when to show the command. To add the command to the editor actions toolbar, add the command under the `contributes.menus.editor/title` menu. If you want it to display as a top level item, set the `group` to `navigation`. You can also (and probably should) set a `when` clause so that the icon only shows when certain conditions are met. ([See the when clause reference](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/when-clause-contexts))
  In the example, the icon will only show on JavaScript files. If you omit the `when` clause, it will always show

Note that when the user clicks on the icon, it will do nothing unless you set a handler function for the command in your extension activation function. Which also means that you have to set the correct `activationEvents` in your `package.json` file as well or the handler won't be set.

Here is a full example of a simple extension that does what you are asking:

package.json (full example)

```json
{
    "name": "my-extension",
    "displayName": "My Custom Extension",
    "description": "Adds a run icon to the top of JavaScript files",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "extension.js",
    "license": "ISC",
    "engines": {
        "vscode": "^1.82.0"
    },
    "activationEvents": [
        "onLanguage:javascript"
    ],
    "contributes": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "Run.JavaScript.File",
                "title": "Run this file",
                "icon": "$(run)"
            }
        ],
        "menus": {
            "editor/title": [
                {
                    "command": "Run.JavaScript.File",
                    "when": "resourceLangId == javascript",
                    "group": "navigation"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

And since I set `main` to `extension.js` in my `package.json` file, you'll need a file named `extension.js` as well. Here is a simple example that will get you started

extension.js

```js
// The main extension file
let vscode = require("vscode")
let childProcess = require("child_process")

module.exports = {
    activate: (context) => {

        // Register the command
        context.subscriptions.push(
            vscode.commands.registerCommand(
                // Name of the command as in the package.json file
                "Run.JavaScript.File",

                // A handler function that gets executed when the command is run
                () => {

                    // You can put anything you want in here.
                    // What do you want to happen when the user clicks the button?

                    // Here, I simply run the javascript file in node and
                    // show an information message when it's complete
                    let runner = childProcess.spawn(
                        "node",

                        // This is the path of the current active file
                        // I'm just passing that directly to node
                        [vscode.window.activeTextEditor.document.uri.path]
                    )

                    let out = ""
                    runner.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
                        out += data.toString("utf-8")
                    })
                    runner.on("close", () => {
                        vscode.window.showInformationMessage("Run completed: " + out)
                    })
                }
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Takeaways: 1. set the icon on the command and not the menu 2. set the appropriate group on the menu for the icon to appear.